# Binary Search and Add in Java

Tags: java

I am to make a search method more efficient and I decided to use binary search. I want to use this search to add each item line number in a word list found to and display the number of times each item is found. But my code does not seem to work...

```
private static void searchAndAdd(List<Word> wl, String w, int ln) {
    boolean found = false;
    Iterator<Word> wit = wl.listIterator();
    int min = 0;
    int max = wl.size()-1;

     int bsearch = binarySearch(wl, w, min, max);
    while (found && wit.hasNext()) {
        Word wd = wit.next();
        if (bsearch == -1 )
        {
            wd.addLineNumber(ln);
        }
    }
    if (!found)
        wl.add(0, new Word(w, ln));
}
 private static int binarySearch(List<Word> arr, String w, int min, int max) {
     if (min < max) {
             return NOT_FOUND;
     }
     int mid = (min + max) /2;
     Word w2 = arr.get(mid);
     if (w.compareTo(w2.toString())  > 0) {
             return binarySearch(arr, w, mid + 1, min);
     } else if (w.compareTo(w2.toString()) < 0) {
             return binarySearch(arr, w, min, mid - 1);
     } else {
             return mid;
     }
```

I always get this error:

```
in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Concordance.binarySearch(Concordance.java:131)
at Concordance.searchAndAdd(Concordance.java:114)
at Concordance.main(Concordance.java:51)
```

Comment: it keeps given me this errorException in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Concordance.binarySearch(Concordance.java:131)
 at Concordance.searchAndAdd(Concordance.java:114)
 at Concordance.main(Concordance.java:51)

Comment: does not seem to add the line.

Comment: it will perform better if it isn't recursive.

Comment: We don't have your line numbers. Please edit your post to show where the NPE is happening.

Comment: You also really need to paste the code that you're actually using into this, not editing it along the way.  Reasons I think this isn't your real code: the "found" variable is never not false, so you don't get into that loop.  Also, the whole min < max thing means that you'd never get far enough into the binarySearch method to get a NPE.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is your only problem, but I suspect that your binary search doesn't ever search for anything because of the lines:

```
if (min < max) {
         return NOT_FOUND;
 }
```

Which is always the case for a non-empty list.

Comment: You might want to consider writing some unit tests on your binary search.  You also have a bug in this line:return binarySearch(arr, w, mid + 1, min);

Comment: Use a debugger, put a breakpoint at that line (the one that compares min and max), and look at the values.